# Firefox has no back button after selecing Google search results

Tags: firefox, browser, virus, firefox-extensions, firefox-quantum

I'm using a friends computer today.  When you select any link in the Google search results it opens the link, in the same tab, but the Firefox browser's back button is grey. I checked the history, and the Google search is there, as the previous page.  A complete Malwarebytes scan is negative.  All add-ons are disabled.  (I disabled them.)

This problem apparently only occurs on the Google search results page.  The back button is working correctly on the other sites I've tried.

Firefox Quantum 61.  Windows 8.

Comment: Even if you have disabled all add-ons, would you give the list of add-ons that are installed. I am not sure but newly introduced Container add-on isolates different websites and is set to automatically open different sites in their own containers, and isolates, so it might be "delinking" the site from history.

Comment: Do you have the Google Container add-on? Make sure it's disabled. I was having the same problem until I turned it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean re-install of Firefox solved the problem.

The question as to what the underlying is was is not resolved.